# Black screen on physical Device but on the simulator works perfectly

Tags: react-native

I suspect this is the problem, since I have added this conditional statement for the gender. When testing on the actual device it show just a black screen. 
While on the simulator it works perfectly. I can't figure out what is wrong

Tried placing the image component in constants but still this happens.

```
  <View style={[styles.infoContainer1, , {justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}]}>
                            {/* <Text style={[styles.infoDetails]}>
                              {item.gender === undefined ? "--" : item.gender}
                            </Text> */}
   {item.gender === undefined ?

    <Image
    source={require('../../assets/images/icon_equality.png')}
    style={[appStyles.genderIcon, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}
  />

   : item.gender === "male" ? 
          <Image
          source={require('../../assets/images/icon_male.png')}
          style={[appStyles.genderIcon, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}
        />

  : item.gender === "female" ?
        <Image
        source={require('../../assets/images/icon_female.png')}
        style={[appStyles.genderIcon, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}
      />
  :

    <Image
      source={require('../../assets/images/icon_not.png')}
      style={[appStyles.genderIcon, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}
    />
                              } 
                          </View>
```

The result should be show an icon for male, female and preferred not to say.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit it is related to the account that is being tested. It has a separate api route that's why it throws an error